# VueJS - Jquery is not defined

Tags: jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to create a Vue component that uses a premade css style, but the problem is that i keep getting the following error, since the template uses bootstrap and bootstrap uses some jquery:

```
custom.js?2435:952 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Code:

component.vue

```
<template>
    <html>
        <body>
        ...
        </body>
    </html>
</template>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="./Crypo/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Crypo/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="./Crypo/assets/js/amcharts-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Crypo/assets/js/amcharts.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Crypo/assets/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="./Crypo/assets/js/custom.js"></script>

<style scoped src="./Crypo/assets/css/style.css"></style>
```

The `Crypo` folder is in the same folder as `component.vue`. I don't understand why isn't jQuery defined even though i'm importing it. I tried to add to my code

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
```

But i'm still getting the error. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options here:

Or you put these links into the index.html

```
- public
  - index.html
```

As it in here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="./Crypo/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Crypo/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Crypo/assets/js/amcharts-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Crypo/assets/js/amcharts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Crypo/assets/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
    <script src="./Crypo/assets/js/custom.js"></script>    
    ...
```

Or instead you install everything through npm (prefered) using [bootstrap-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-vue)

```
npm install vue bootstrap-vue bootstrap
```

And import it in your app entrypoint like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
// bootstrap lib import
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
// css imports
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Install BootstrapVue
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
```

Another thing is, you shouldn't use html nor body tags in vue components, they should be used only in the index.html file.